# Jmeter applying load with limited number of users

Tags: jmeter

I have a very few actually a couple of users for a particular profile. Will it be a good performance test only with these 2 users? May be putting them in a loop with a timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking concurrency that it is not a good idea. If the user is allowed to have multiple sessions then you can try to reuse the same user in multiple jmeter threads.